# passing a class thread parameters

Tags: c++, multithreading

im new here and i need some help for a project:
My project was to merge two pictures and each threads got the mission to merge its part.

this my code:

```
class Partie_Gauche {
public:
    IMAGE & pict1;
    IMAGE & pict2;
    double beta;
    double omega;
    Partie_Gauche(IMAGE & image_1, IMAGE & image_2, double ruine, double b)
        :pict1(image_1), pict2(image_2), beta(ruine), omega(b) {};
};


DWORD WINAPI Second_thread(LPVOID lpParam)
{

    Partie_Gauche *m_thread = (Partie_Gauche*)lpParam;
    DWORD idThread = GetCurrentThreadId(); //recupere l'identifiant du thread
    int zeta = m_thread->omega;
    for (int x = ((zeta * 1.0) / nbreThreads)*m_thread->pict1.width(); x < ((1.0 + zeta)*m_thread->pict1.width()) / nbreThreads; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < m_thread->pict1.height(); y++)
        {
            for (int c = 0; c < m_thread->pict1.spectrum(); c++)  // les plans de couleur(R, G, B)
            {
                // détermination du ceof de pondération en fonction de la coordonnée y du pixel
                double coef = m_thread->beta*(1 - double(y) / m_thread->pict1.height());

                // somme pondérée des pixels
                m_thread->pict1(x, y, 0, c) = (unsigned char)((1 - m_thread->beta)*m_thread->pict1(x, y, 0, c) + coef*m_thread->pict2(x, y, 0, c));
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;

}
```

finally I create my threads :

```
    'HANDLE tabThread[nbreThreads];
    Partie_Gauche* m_Thd[nbreThreads];

    for (int y(0); y > nbreThreads;y++)
        m_Thd[y] = new Partie_Gauche(imageA, imageB, 0.5, (double)y);


    for (int i = 0; i < nbreThreads; i++)
        tabThread[i] = CreateThread(NULL, 0, Second_thread, &m_Thd[i], NULL, NULL);



    WaitForMultipleObjects(nbreThreads, tabThread, true, INFINITE);  '
```

And then the compiler indicates me an exception of violating memory access.
I dont understand why. Thanks

Comment: `for (int y(0); y > nbreThreads;y++)` Surely you meant `y < nbreThreads`. As written, the first loop doesn't run, and `m_Thd` elements remain uninitialized.

Comment: Another problem: `&m_Thd[i]` is `Partie_Gauche**` - a pointer to a pointer to `Partie_Gauche`. But the thread casts it to `Partie_Gauche*`. Drop the ampersand when calling `CreateThread`.

Comment: i initialized m_Thd there : IMAGE imageA("img\\Stonehenge.pnm");
  IMAGE imageB("img\\sh0r.pgm");

Comment: thanks Igor you just solved my problem !! ;)